# Vector3.MoveTowards not working properly for 2D pathfinding

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am in the process of trying to make a simple 2D pathfinding NPC in my Unity game that will walk from waypoint to waypoint. I am using an array of waypoints and Vector3.MoveTowards to move in between the points but every time I test it, the NPC will move towards the first waypoint for a second and then starts traveling down the screen and away from the waypoint forever. I'm not sure why it keeps doing this. Here are snippets of the code I'm using:

```
public float speed = 1f;
public Transform[] waypoints;
private int curWaypoint;
void Start()
{
    curWaypoint = 0;
}

void Update()
{
    MoveForward();
}

void MoveForward(){
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, 
                                            waypoints[curWaypoint].transform.position,
                                            Time.deltaTime * speed);
    if(transform.position == waypoints[curWaypoint].transform.position){
        curWaypoint += 1;
    }
    if(curWaypoint == waypoints.Length){
        curWaypoint = 0;
    }
}
```

The waypoints are just empty GameObjects with a gizmo on them so they can be seen in the editor. I then populate the waypoints array in the inspector with the waypoint I want the NPC to follow. I can't figure out what is causing this odd behavior so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Code looks fine to me. Are there any other components attached to the NPC such as rigidbodies or other scripts? Also, `waypoints[curWaypoint]` is already a `Transform` so you can just do `waypoints[curWaypoint].position`.

Comment: Your code works just fine for me if you create a new project, create a sphere and attach [this script](https://pastebin.com/0JqrGFG5) to the sphere.  It seems like something else is interfering with your code. There's no way anyone can help you without more information.

Comment: Just a general note: You could use [`Vector2.MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.MoveTowards.html) for a 2D game

Comment: I figured out the issue. I had a RigidBody2D attached to my NPC that I intended on using later and forgot to turn off the effects of gravity (it's a top-down game). Thanks for the input!